# Oracle Apex get Multiple results from checkboxes

Tags: oracle, checkbox, oracle11g, oracle-apex

DB = Oracle 11g

Apex = 4.2.6

In the form I have various items which all work great. However I now have a set of check boxes(:P14_DAYS) one for each day of the week. 
What I need to do is get all records between :P14_START_DATE :P14_END_DATE, but only within the days select that's checked.

Below is also a sample of the DATE_SETS table

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAckN.png

so for example 
dates 01-AUG-14 - 5-AUG-14 But only require Sundays AND Mondays date would bring back 2 refs.

```
BEGIN 
UPDATE MD_TS_DETAIL 
SET    job_for = :P14_JOBFORTEM, 
       job_type_id = :P14_JOB_TYPE_VALUE, 
       account_id = :P14_ACC_VAL, 
       qty = :P14_HRS, 
       rio = :P14_RIO, 
       post_code = :P14_POSTCODE 
WHERE  id IN (SELECT D.id 
              FROM   MD_TS_MAST M 
                     LEFT JOIN MD_TS_DETAIL D 
                            ON M.mast_id = D.md_id 
                     LEFT JOIN DATE_SETS 
                            ON ms_date = dt 
              WHERE  eng_id = :P14_ENG_VAL 
                     AND ms_date BETWEEN :P14_START_DATE AND :P14_END_DATE 
                     AND DATE_SETS.col_day = ANY instr(':'||:P14_DAYS||':',Return)
END;
```

Any help would be much appreciated .

Comment: Do you already have checkboxes in your report or you need to add them too?

Comment: Yep, item :P14_DAYS. Checkbox are set from a LOV MON:MONDAY;TUE:TUESDAY and so on

Comment: First I thought you have a column of checkboxes in a report. Unfortunately, I never used checkboxes in a LOV before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this example: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B31036_01/doc/appdev.22/b28839/check_box.htm#CHDBGDJH
As I can understand, when you choose some values in your checkbox list, item `:P14_DAYS` receives value, that contains return values of chosen elements of the LOV with delimiters. Then you need to replace this string in your query

```
AND DATE_SETS.col_day = ANY instr(':'||:P14_DAYS||':',Return)
```

with

```
AND instr(':'||:P14_DAYS||':', ':'||DATE_SETS.col_day||':') > 0
```

Here function `instr` searches substring `DATE_SETS.col_day` in string `:P14_DAYS`. It returns position of substring if substring was found or 0, if not found. Then you compare result of function with 0, and if result > 0, it means that `DATE_SETS.col_day` is among selected values.